# Better Debuggin Info with monodroid?

Tags: xamarin.android

I am in debug mode and when a line crashes it does not give very much information(no exception)

All I get is

> This is the next statement to execute when this thread returns from
>   the current function.

Then the debugger usually detaches itself if I try to go to the next line.

```
  StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(e.Result);
  var test=  JSON.Instance.ToObject<Test>(reader.ReadToEnd());
  txtView.Text = test.Date;
```

It will update the textView but then it will go back to the StreamReader line and will display the above message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debugger performance in the current version of Mono for Android is definitely less than ideal. The best way to get debug information from your app is to make use of the Android Debug Log, which you can access through Visual Studio, the command line, or [DDMS](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/ddms.html). Xamarin has good documentation of how to read and use that log up [available here](http://android.xamarin.com/Documentation/Guides/Android_Debug_Log). You'll be able to see log statements that you put in your app, and will also get full stacktraces of any crashes that occur.